# 2nd JOptionPane won't come up

Tags: java

I'm just starting out with Java and programming in general. Could someone please explain to me why the second dialog box won't show up after I've entered the information for the first one?

Thanks!

```
// Java Practice

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DialogTest 
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String firstname;
        String lastname;
        int age;

        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is " +
                                    "your first name?");
        firstname = keyboard.nextLine();

        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is " +
                                    "your last name?");
        lastname = keyboard.nextLine();

        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How old are you?");
        age = keyboard.nextInt();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I see, so your name is: " + firstname + lastname + " and you are" + age + " years old.");

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` returns a `String` that contains the value entered by the user. Instead of using the `Scanner` class, store the return value of the method call into your variables:

```
String firstname, lastname, age;

firstname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is " +
                                "your first name?");

lastname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is " +
                                "your last name?");

age = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How old are you?");

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I see, so your name is: " + firstname + lastname + " and you are" + age + " years old.");
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need both `JOptionPane` and `Scanner`. You only need one (I highly recommend `Scanner` over the other).

What's happening is this: The call to `JOptionPane` is opening a dialog for your user to enter a value. That value is returned by this method call, which you do nothing with. Then *after* the dialog is finished, you call `keyboard.nextLine()` which blocks the program until the user enters *another* value *into the command line window* (or your IDE if you're running it through that).

If you want to see both options available to you, try commenting out the `keyboard` lines and setting `firstname = JOptionPane...` and so on. Once you've tried out that program, do the opposite: comment out the `JOptionPane` calls and replace them with `System.out.println` calls.

As someone who began learning input handling via `JOptionPane`, I believe `Scanner` is a much better utility.

Comment: I'll try that and keep your advice in mind. Thanks for the detailed answer.